# Volume of a rescaled Stiefel manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, volume, stiefel-manifolds

The volume of the complex Stiefel manifold (where $n>p$)
$$\mathcal{S}(n,p)=\{\boldsymbol{Q}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times p}|\boldsymbol{Q}^{\rm H}\boldsymbol{Q}=\boldsymbol{I}\}
$$
is given by
$$
{\rm Vol}(\mathcal{S}(n,p))=\prod_{k=n-p+1}^n\frac{2\pi^k}{(k-1)!},
$$
which is a standard result.

Now, I am trying to compute the volume of the following manifold
$$
\mathcal{S}_{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}=\{\boldsymbol{Q}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times p}|\boldsymbol{Q}^{\rm H}\boldsymbol{Q}=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\},
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times p}$ is a diagonal matrix with real positive diagonal entries. I am aware that it is a rescaled version of the Stiefel manifold, which should correspond to a certain metric transformation. But I had a really hard time trying to write that specific transformation down... Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: How does the volume of a sphere scale when you make it an ellipsoid?